# Counter Using Javascript, HTML & CSS Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, counter, countdowntimer

Can anyone help me to get this (https://jsfiddle.net/hmatrix/v3jncqac/) code to work?

**Inentention:** I want to create a counter that increases in increments.

**My HTML:**

```
<body onload="incrementCount(10)">
    <div class="main_container" id="id_main_container">
        <div class="container_inner" id="display_div_id">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**My JS:**

```
var counter_list = [10,10000,10000];
var str_counter_0 = counter_list[0];
var str_counter_1 = counter_list[1];
var str_counter_2 = counter_list[2];
var display_str = "";
var display_div = document.getElementById("display_div_id");

function incrementCount(current_count){
    setInterval(function(){
        // clear count
        while (display_div.hasChildNodes()) {
            display_div.removeChild(display_div.lastChild);
        }
        str_counter_0++;
        if (str_counter_0 > 99) {
            str_counter_0 = 0; // reset count
            str_counter_1++;    // increase next count
        }
        if(str_counter_1>99999){
            str_counter_2++;
        }
        display_str = str_counter_2.toString() + str_counter_1.toString() + str_counter_0.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < display_str.length; i++) {
            var new_span = document.createElement('span');
            new_span.className = 'num_tiles';
            new_span.innerText = display_str[i];
            display_div.appendChild(new_span);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: please click the jsfiddle link for the CSS

Comment: Where you placed your code ? in `<head>` ? or at the end of `<body>`? Code is good check your console in DevTools

Comment: If you looked at your developer console, you would also see WHY it is not working. Error message is clear as day in the log. Use your developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <body onload="incrementCount(10)">
    <div class="main_container" id="id_main_container">
        <div class="container_inner" id="display_div_id">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
var counter_list = [10,10000,10000];
var str_counter_0 = counter_list[0];
var str_counter_1 = counter_list[1];
var str_counter_2 = counter_list[2];
var display_str = "";
var display_div = document.getElementById("display_div_id");

function incrementCount(current_count){
    setInterval(function(){
        // clear count
        while (display_div.hasChildNodes()) {
            display_div.removeChild(display_div.lastChild);
        }
        str_counter_0++;
        if (str_counter_0 > 99) {
            str_counter_0 = 0; // reset count
            str_counter_1++;    // increase next count
        }
        if(str_counter_1>99999){
            str_counter_2++;
        }
        display_str = str_counter_2.toString() + str_counter_1.toString() + 
str_counter_0.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < display_str.length; i++) {
            var new_span = document.createElement('span');
            new_span.className = 'num_tiles';
            new_span.innerText = display_str[i];
            display_div.appendChild(new_span);
        }
    },1000);
}
</script>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/v3jncqac/32/

Your onload function cannot find the function because your js is in a different file. you need to add script src on top of html or do it as shown above.